# NSWindow maximized?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, maximize

does anybody know a correct solution for this code?

```
BOOL maximized = [myWindow isMaximized];
```

Comment: There is no such concept as "maximizing a window" on the Mac. What specifically are you thinking of? Having hit the zoom button? Being in a fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe take a look at [`isZoomed`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to maximize your NSWindow then you will have to set its frame size to the main screen size, as below

```
NSWindow* myWindow; //Your window object to maximize
```

`[myWindow setFrame:[[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame] display:YES];`

Comment: It might be better to use the screen that the window is on and not the main screen. `[myWindow setFrame:[[myWindow screen] frame] display YES];`

Answer (score 2):

There's not such thing as a maximized window in OSX. isZoomed is the closest approximation, but that also returns true:

- in full screen mode.
- for windows with NSBorderlessWindowMask style.

(tested with OS X 10.9)